# java example for sending avro/bytes POST request to server

Tags: java, scala, http, rest, avro

I'm interested in sending `avro/bytes` (raw bytes) in `POST` request into a server.  Before handcoding anything of my own i wanted to check out some ready made example and found none yet..  Anyone has any example of how to send `avro/bytes` encoded `POST` request body into a server? (bytes encoded into `avro/bytes` but **not to `base64`** etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your object to avro and then to bytes and then you can use this simple method(using apache httpcore) to get the response (this method assumes that the server response with json string)

```
 public static String postJSON(String uri, byte[] req) {
    String queryResponse = null;
    try {
        List<Header> httpHeaders = new ArrayList<Header>();
        httpHeaders.add(HttpClientUtil.ACCEPT_TEXT_HTML);
        HttpResponse response = HttpClientUtil.post(uri, req, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, httpHeaders);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        queryResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return queryResponse;
  }
```